# get the first and last emitted values from an observable

Tags: rxjs, observable

Is there a way to get the first and last emitted values from an observable?

```
const down$ = fromEvent(this.canvas, 'mousedown');
const up$ = fromEvent(this.canvas, 'mouseup');
const move$ = fromEvent(this.canvas, 'mousemove');
const drag$ = move$.pipe(
  skipUntil(down$),
  takeUntil(up$)
);
drag$.subscribe((e: MouseEvent) => {
  console.log(e);
});
```

Is there a way to get the first and last values from the

```
drag$
```

observable?

Answer (score 4):

You can get the first and the last values from an Observable with `take(1)` and `takeLast(1)` operators.

```
import { range, merge, Subject } from 'rxjs';
import { take, takeLast, multicast } from 'rxjs/operators';

range(1, 10)
  .pipe(
    multicast(() => new Subject(), o => merge(
      o.pipe(take(1)),
      o.pipe(takeLast(1)),
    )),
  )
  .subscribe(v => console.log('result', v));
```

In your case it looks like you could do something like this but I don't know what exactly is you goal:

```
down$
  .pipe(
    switchMap(() => move$.pipe(
      takeUntil(up$),
      multicast(() => new Subject(), o => merge(
        o.pipe(take(1)),
        o.pipe(takeLast(1)),
      )),
    )),
  )
  .subscribe(console.log);
```

See live demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs6-demo-ymjoiy?file=index.ts

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I was making things too complicated. This is my final code:

```
const up$ = fromEvent(this.canvas, 'mouseup');
const down$ = fromEvent(this.canvas, 'mousedown');
const drag$ = down$.pipe(merge(up$));
drag$.subscribe((e: MouseEvent) => console.log(e); });
```